# Reinstall Internet Explorer 11

Tags: powershell, cmd

For testing porposes I uninstalled IE 11 with this command:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object name -Like Browser.InternetExplorer~~~~0.0.11.0 | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

What I did:
Tried to reinstalled with

```
DISM /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Browser.InternetExplorer~~~~* /Source:F: /LimitAccess
```

How it could be reinstalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open ISO file and copy

..\sources\sxs\microsoft-windows-internetexplorer-optional-package.cab

DISM /online /add-package /packagepath:d:\microsoft-windows-internetexplorer-optional-package.cab